# can ntohs() apply on uint8_t

Tags: c, byte, endianness

```
int main()    
{ 
   uint8_t var = 9;  
   var = ntohs(var);
   printf("var=%u",var)
}
```

the piece of code yields var value as 0 in Little Endian, But in Big Endian 9 becomes possible answer.

As of my guess, as we can't apply ntohs on 1 byte filed!! can we? is there any case?.

my linux machine is Little Endian ,x86 architecture, Intel

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between "in my project" and "i tried".

Comment: the same code var value results once 0 aswell 9 also.

Comment: On same machine?

Comment: If printed properly the output should not be 0.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile and run that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @dbush If network is BE and the host is LE - it should be 0 I think....

Comment: @EugeneSh. If that's the case, it should be 2304 (0x0900).

Comment: @dbush `var` is `uint8_t`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Right you are.

Comment: So I don't get the  question. Are you getting `0` or `9`?

Comment: FYI, i am wondered why var giving value as 9 when this piece of code executed in my hardware(remote device). but when i executed in my linux terminal i am getting 0.

Comment: Where is it "giving" it? After the `printf` (which is "giving" you `0`, as far as I understand) the program is done.

Comment: What is you hardware? Is it a different system than the "linux" one? Then it is probably having a different endianess. Your question has to provide *all* of this information, otherwise you are just wasting our time.

Comment: something beyond is there, so that i am getting 9 value also, ntohs on uint8_t works expected!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `var` is `uint8_t`. The signature for `ntohs` is `uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);`, meaning it's returning a 16 bit int, which is then being stored in an 8 bit int.

When you pass var to `ntohs`, your 8 bit int is promoted to a 16 bit int. Your machine is little endian, hence as a 16 bit int, 9 is `0x0009`. `ntohs` interprets its argument as a network order 16 bit int, hence it reads `0x0009` as 2304. It then tries to turn this into little endian order, because your machine is little endian.

In little endian, `2304` is `0x0900`. `ntohs` then returns this, but `var` is only 8 bits long, so it chops off the left byte, hence storing `0x00`. This explains why you're getting 0 as your output.

If you change `var` to be `uint16_t`, you should get `2304` out as expected.

You will never get a `9` out unless you're running on a big endian machine.

Comment: @Razgriz you don't use `ntohs` and `htons` on a `uint8_t`. The whole point of those functions is to change the order of the bytes, and a `uint8_t` is only a single byte, so there's nothing to change

Answer (score 3):

On a little endian machine, 0 is the expected output.  On a big endian machine, it will output 9.

When `var`, which has a value of 0x09, is passed to `ntohs` it is first promoted to `uint16_t` which is the type of the parameter, so the parameter has value 0x0009.  After the conversion, the function returns the value 0x0900 as type `uint16_t`.

This value is then assigned to a `uint8_t` but the value 0x0900 is out of range.  It is then converted to the smaller value by essentially just using the lowest order byte of the value, which is 0.

If you ran this same code on a big-endian machine, the `ntohs` function basically does nothing and returns the same value it was given, in this case 9.